# Deriving the error in activation nodes in back propagation algorithm

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, machine-learning, neural-networks

I am trying to understand back propagation algorithm from Andrew Ng's Machine learning course.
[Here is a pitcure of the slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZkSc.png) on which I am stuck.

I know that error in a function $f(x)$ is calculated as:

$f(x+\Delta x) - f(x) = f'(x) * \Delta x$

But I am unable to understand how $\delta^{(3)}$ is calculated as:

$\delta^{(3)} = (\Theta^{(3)})^T * \delta^{(4)} .* g'(z^{(3)})$

where $\delta^{(3)}_j$ is error in node j of layer 3.

EDIT 1: After searching on coursera's discussion forum I found some help.

According to the [week 5 lecture notes](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/resources/EcbzQ) (under the heading Backpropagation Intuition):

> Intuitively, $\delta_j^{(l)}$ is the "error" for $a^{(l)}_j$ (unit j
>   in layer l)

and

> More formally, the delta values are actually the derivative of the
>   cost function
>
> $\delta_j^{(l)} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z_j^{(l)}} cost(t)$

Using above information when I was trying to compute $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z_j^{(l)}} cost(t)$ I got a doubt.

If $\delta_j^{(l)}$ is error in $a^{(l)}_j$ then why is $\delta_j^{(l)}$ defined as partial derivative of cost function with respect to $z^{(3)}_j$ where $z^{(3)}_j=\Theta^{(2)}_ja^{(2)}_j$ and not with respect to $\Theta^{(l)}_j$  or $a^{(2)}_j$

EDIT 2:

On further searching I found the derivation of errors on [week 5 lecture notes](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/resources/EcbzQ) and now I am stuck at a new place. If $J(\Theta)$ is defined as $J(\Theta)=−ylog(h\Theta(x))−(1−y)log(1−h\Theta(x))$ then how is

$\dfrac{\partial J(\Theta)}{\partial\Theta^{(L−1)}}=\dfrac{\partial J(\Theta)}{\partial a^{(L)}}\dfrac{\partial a^{(L)}}{\partial z^{(L)}}\dfrac{\partial z^{(L)}}{\partial\Theta^{(L−1)}}$

I know that chain rule is used in the above equation but cannot figure out how

Comment: What doesn’t make sense? Some part of the equation or the entire equation itself?

Comment: The entire equation itself.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw this again... reply to my comment if you still do not understand the original equation, but in this comment I will just explain your edit. Generally speaking, in neural networks, error is a function of not just weights or $\Theta$, but also of the node itself or $a_j^{(l)}$. You want to see how your $\delta$ varies with your _prediction_ rather than just weights... Does that make sense?